# Basic Collision Code in C#- Collision not Detecting

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection

I'm having some problems with a fairly basic platforming game I'm attempting to make. I'm trying to write collision code so that the player can land on individuals random platforms which come from a list, but despite various things I've tried, the boolean I'm using to control whether the character is experiencing gravity or not isn't reaching a value of false when the character steps off a platform, so they can float through the air in either direction. They also sink into the platform, but I'd like to make them stand on top.

The player class takes a position vector, a velocity vector, a direction string and a boolean for whether it's landed as parameters. The code in the update method is as follows, but I'll also put in the code that determines whether an object is on top.

```
character.position += character.velocity;

 if (character.landed == false)
                    character.velocity.Y = character.velocity.Y + 0.15f;
                else character.velocity.Y = 0;
            foreach (Platform p in Platforms)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < p.size; i++)
                {
                    if ((isOnTopOf(character.position, charRSprite, new Vector2(p.xPos + (32 * i), p.yPos), grassBlock) == true)
                        || (isOnTopOf(character.position, charLSprite, new Vector2(p.xPos + (32 * i), p.yPos), grassBlock) == true))
                    {
                        character.landed = true;
                    }
                    if ((isOnTopOf(character.position, charRSprite, new Vector2(p.xPos + (32 * i), p.yPos), grassBlock) == true) 
                        && character.position.X + 3f > p.xPos + (32*p.size)
                      || (isOnTopOf(character.position, charLSprite, new Vector2(p.xPos + (32 * i), p.yPos), grassBlock) == true)
                        && character.position.X -3f < p.xPos)
                    {
                        character.landed = false;
                    }

                } 

            }
            if (InputHandler.KeyPressed(Keys.Left))
            {
                character.velocity.X = -3f;
                character.direction = "Left";
            }
            if (InputHandler.KeyPressed(Keys.Right))
            {
                character.velocity.X = +3f;
                character.direction = "Right";
            }
            if ((InputHandler.KeyPressed(Keys.Space) || InputHandler.KeyPressed(Keys.W)) && character.landed == true)
            {
                character.position.Y = character.position.Y - 10f;
                character.velocity.Y = -7.5f;
                character.landed = false;
            }
            if (character.position.Y > 3000)
            {
                GameRef.Exit();
            }
        }
```

The collision boolean is as follows:

```
    public bool isOnTopOf(Vector2 item1Position, Texture2D item1Sprite, Vector2 item2Position, Texture2D item2Sprite)
    {
        area1.X = (int)item1Position.X;
        area1.Y = (int)item1Position.Y;
        area2.X = (int)item2Position.X;
        area2.Y = (int)item2Position.Y;
        area1.Width = item1Sprite.Width;
        area1.Height = item1Sprite.Height;
        area2.Width = item2Sprite.Width;
        area2.Height = item2Sprite.Height;

        return (area1.Bottom >= area2.Top - 3 && area1.Bottom <= area2.Top + 3 && area1.Right >= area2.Left - 3 
            && area1.Left <= area2.Right + 3);
    }
```

I'd really appreciate any help that won't require me to remove all of the code I've done so far, but will allow me to slightly adapt it. I'm under time constraints... Also, the following code (included in 1st code segment) was a part which I added to stop the character from walking air off the platform, which for some reason didn't return true.

```
if ((isOnTopOf(character.position, charRSprite, new Vector2(p.xPos + (32 * i), p.yPos), grassBlock) == true) 
                    && character.position.X + 3f > p.xPos + (32*p.size)
                  || (isOnTopOf(character.position, charLSprite, new Vector2(p.xPos + (32 * i), p.yPos), grassBlock) == true)
                    && character.position.X -3f < p.xPos)
                {
                    character.landed = false;
                }
```

Comment: I assume that the call to IsOnTopOf() is always returning false.  Might be worth sticking a System.Diagnostic.Debug.WriteLine() to output that characters Y position when it does return false.  My guess is that you've probably got your offsets slightly misaligned, or your checks are not consistent (it's difficult to tell without spinning it up and running the code, but I notice you have >= in some places and > in others)

Comment: I'm pretty new to programming , so I'm not really sure how to use Debug.WriteLine()... I tried to adjust the offsets of isOnTopOf, but if I make them greater values the character levitates above the platform, yet values 3 and lower make them sink into the platform. I was just using > as a separate test to see whether the character would move past the platforms bounds if they were to move, which I realize is probably not a good system. I don't understand why the last bit of code I've add never works, because the isontopof code is identical to the previous one, where it returns true.

Comment: Basically, you put something inside the paramenthesis; for example:  
System.Diagnostic.Debug.WriteLine(character.position.x);  
And the resultant debug information will be displayed in your Output window (in VS View -> Output if you can't see it)

Comment: Makes sense... apparently Diagnostic does not exist within system for me though. Thanks for all of your help so far though!

Comment: Sorry - it's Diagnostics: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline?view=netframework-4.7.2  If you're not seeing something inside a namespace, use ctrl-space in VS - it'll sometimes give you an idea what you want.

Comment: Alright thanks, I used that to have a look, though I couldn't work out how to check the isontopof value, which I thought might be helpful. I changed my code to this:

Comment: Sorry for all of that (everything I sent earlier). I've finally got it to  if ((isOnTopOf(character.position, charRSprite, new Vector2(p.xPos, p.yPos), grassBlock) == true)
                            || (isOnTopOf(character.position, 
                            charLSprite, new Vector2(p.xPos, p.yPos), grassBlock) == true))
                        {
                            character.landed = true;
                        }

Comment: and else makes landed false, but the problem is that the else code is executing whenever there is more than one platform, as it runs for each platform. Is there a way I can specify the platform? As I'm randomly generating an unlimited amount of platforms, I don't think I could use an index for a platform, as there's no way I could specify the index for each platform every time.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each platform and select the closest platform with respect to the velocity/position of the player, to collide with.